# renaming tables/columns on SQL Server/Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to rename tables/columns on SQL Server via Visual Studio that refactors all the code that manipulates it?

I've renamed my tables/columns via SP_RENAME on Visual Studio query console and it worked but now I have hundreds of errors because I have a lot of code that queries/inserts data in those tables and they still with their old names on my C# code.

Thank you.

Comment: Global search and replace would be my recommendation.  (Well, my first recommendation would have been to not rename tables and columns without a *really* compelling reason).

Comment: I believe redgate refactor does this. But now you've already renamed them probably too late.